# Button Alignment on Android

Tags: android, button, layout, graphics

I am new at the android and I have an issue on button alignment I am trying to align some buttons but I cannot succeed the exact result I want. I will provide you an image on the result I want to succeed[image]

The xml I have created is this `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bgmedium" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
        android:text="@string/come_to_us" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
        android:text="@string/car_exhibition" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
        android:text="@string/test_drive" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
        android:text="@string/phone_contact" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
        android:text="@string/website" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

But the result looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly i suggest that to use LinearLayout for this screen. I will be simpler with linearLayout. You can use gravity property inside button elements to align center your button's texts.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

### Edit

Result:

[image: Result]

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/genel_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/GirisButton"
        android:text="Button1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/GirisButton"
        android:text="Button2" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/GirisButton"
        android:text="Button3" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/GirisButton"
        android:text="Button4" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/GirisButton"
        android:text="Button5" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

style element

```
 <style name="GirisButton">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/giris_button_combined</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I tried what you proposed but still I have a weird view. Better from the previous view but still the text is aligned more to the right. @Göksel Güren

Comment: I am writing some code for you bro. I will share soon.

Comment: Thank you man! I am tried to use alsod DroidDraw, without any results. :(

Comment: I will give it a try my friend and I will let you know! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you bro! You provided me a better view. I will try to work harder the designing staff. I did more backend development so I should get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add margins and/or paddings to each of the buttons to get the layout that you want, try this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/come_to_us" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
    android:text="@string/car_exhibition"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
    android:text="@string/test_drive"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
    android:text="@string/phone_contact"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:background="@drawable/button_medium"
    android:text="@string/website"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

Android has guidelines for its UI that you can follow, this may help http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html